# Expand permutation matrix

Tags: graph-theory

Let $A$ be a $k$ by $n$ matrix where the rows are permutations of $\{1,2,3,..,n\}$ and in each column all elements are different (i.e columns are subsets of permutations of $\{1,2,3,..,n\}$). 
Show that there exists an $n$ by $n$ matrix $B$ such that each row and column is a permutation of $\{1,2,3,..,n\}$ and its first $k$ rows are the rows of $A$.

I can see that this should be an application of Hall's theorem but I'm having trouble choosing the graph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that matchings in a bipartite graph will allow you to find $B$. Here is a hint. Consider the bipartite graph with bipartition $(C,D)$ where $C$ corresponds to the columns of $A$ and $D$ corresponds to the numbers $1,2\ldots,n$. Join column $i$ to number $j$ if $j$ is not found in column $i$. Show that this graph is $n-k$-regular. Now what do you know about matchings in regular bipartite graphs?

Comment: A perfect matching exists from Hall's condition, and then I can do induction on $n-k$?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat Yes and if you haven't seen the theorem that regular bipartite graphs always have a perfect matching, it can be proved using Hall's condition.

Comment: Yeah, I can see it, thanks